# Is there a solution to why I can't pip install any python modules past 2.7?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, module, pip

I can't install any python modules that require python 2.7 or later. I have uninstalled everything that Mac would let me that was related to python 2, and I run everything on python 3. I am completely lost. I am on Mac and whenever I try to install a module(like praw) this pops up.

I used the command

```
pip install praw
```

````
Collecting praw
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/89/94c1ec81a05536e2c2a1dc2e8f5402c8ad65963f28948bf41c64621e238b/praw-6.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
ERROR: Package 'praw' requires a different Python: 2.7.16 not in '>=3.5' ```
````

Comment: Please share the command(s) you executed. Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are doing. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Run `which pip` and investigate if the pip you are running actually goes with your Python 3.

Comment: Try `pip install praw --no-cache-dir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Malachi! I believe you're looking for the command `pip3` (`pip3 install praw`) to install Python 3 packages through pip. If you open your terminal and type `man pip` to get the manual page, there is a line that says:

> pip is the command to use when installing packages for Python 2, while pip3 is the command to use when installing packages for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the most recent version of [`praw`](https://pypi.org/project/praw/) requires Python 3.5 or greater.

The last version that supported Python 2.7 was [praw 5.4.0](https://pypi.org/project/praw/5.4.0/). If you're still using Python 2.7 and need this package, try running

```
pip install praw==5.4.0
```

If you're using Python 3.x, check to see if you're using the right version of `pip`. If you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on your system, you'll likely need to install system wide packages using `pip3` instead if `pip`. In this case, try running

```
pip3 install praw
```

Alternatively, if you're targeting a specific Python interpreter (e.g. `python3.7`, `python3.8`, etc), and want to be certain that you are using the correct `pip` executable for your interpreter, you can run pip as a Python package via

```
python3 -m pip <args>
```

where `python3` can be replaced by any interpreter path.